# Why one facebook have two id

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Why one facebook have two id:

https://graph.facebook.com/1000059xxxxxxxx

https://graph.facebook.com/2392797xxxxxxxx

they are same facebook account, WHY?

Answer (score 1):

Most likely one is the "real" (or "global") ID, the other one is an "App Scoped ID". See the changelog for more information: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog#v2_0_graph_api

You don´t get the global IDs anymore (except for browsing through a Facebook Page), and there is no way to match global IDs with App Scoped ones.

Comment: Thx , luschn.    how can i get the orginal ID?

Comment: i got two facebook id  following api :

Comment: how can i know if they are same account?  Thank you.

Comment: you can´t get the real id anymore, if it would be possible the whole concept with the app scoped ids would make no sense.

Comment: page ids are always "global" btw, they are not app scoped. there´s a big difference between a facebook page and a user profile.

Comment: 2. graph.facebook.com/v2.0/ + page_id + "/feed" From   ==> i means the user who post or comment msg to the page.     "from": {
        "id": "101527941xxxxxxxx", 
        "name": "Kenneth"
      }   i always got the orginal ID.

Comment: i need to know the guy who post msg to my page and the guy who access my website if are same guy.

Comment: page_id suggests that you are using a facebook page id. as i said, page ids are always "global". what is the page id exactly?

Comment: anyway, what you are trying to achieve is not possible at all. on the page you will get global ids, on your website you will get app scoped ones. there is no way to match global ids with app scoped ids.